# undefined method ip for nil Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, model

I am trying to have a model Method return information from an associated model. It works without any issues on the Rails console and also outputs the information on the console when it's running as the web server.

To me it doesn't seem very difficult. But it's not working.

```
class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ip_addresses
  has_one :status

  def first_ip
    @computer = Computer.find(self.id)
    @computer.ip_addresses.first.ip
    end
end


class IpAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ip
  belongs_to :computers
end

[2011-10-10 16:09:02] ERROR ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `ip' for nil:NilClass
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
    /Users/robertg/RubymineProjects/CMDBTEST/app/models/computer.rb:7:in `first_ip'
```

Thanks

Comment: Whats the length of @computer.ip_addresses array. Does it have any values. Seems first is returning nil, so no ip addresses are associated with the Computer.

Comment: You don't need this bit, `@computer = Computer.find(self.id)`. Self is already a `Computer` ;P

Comment: As a side note, `belongs_to` associations should always be singular, since you can only reference one ID. If you really want an `IpAddress` to belong to multiple computers, you should be using either `has_and_belongs_to_many`, or a two-way `has_many :through` association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ip_addresses
  has_one :status

  def first_ip
    first_ip_address = ip_addresses.first
    first_ip_address ? first_ip_address.ip : nil
  end
end
```

Using your method, if the `Computer` has no `ip_addresses`, then calling `.first` will return `nil`, and there is no `ip` method for `NilClass` (just like the error says). This way, it checks if there are any `ip_addresses`, and if so returns the `ip` of the first `ip_address`, and if not returns nil.

Comment: You could also use try. `ip_addresses.first.try(:ip)`

Comment: You're right, that is definitely a more succinct way to do it.

Comment: I think my initial problem was that i was trying to access Model Variables that were not yet associated with any instance variables.